# Regex find pattern not preceded by other pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
text etxta #aaaaaa#bys1a asdasd
a#bbbbbbbys1a asdasd
test style="color: #cccccc"
```

I want the following pattern: `/#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}/`
not preceded by `color:` with optional whitespace.

So the result I expect from the example above is:

```
#aaaaaa
#bbbbbb
```

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? By "optional whitespace", do you mean zero or one space, or any number of spaces?

Comment: I use both php (preg_match_all) and javascript (regex.exec()).
By optional i mean, that it could be `color:#` or `color: #`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind ([see demo](http://regex101.com/r/wQ4oT9/1)):

```
(?<!color: ?)(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})
```

Note however that this version doesn't work if you have multiple or no whitespaces after `:`. That's because lookbehinds can't be variable-length (in most implementations anyway).

---

If your regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds, you can use this expression instead. The advantage this has over the lookbehind version is that it will allow the whitespace after `:` to be optional:

```
color:\s*#[a-z]{6}|(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})
```

The trick is that we match what we don't want on the left side of the alternation (`|`) (i.e. the hex code that is preceded by `color:`, and then we capture what we *do* want on the right side. See [this page](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) to read in detail about this matching technique.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wQ4oT9/3)

Comment: This doesn't account for the requirement to have the whitespace between `color:` and `#` be optional.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, indeed. I've edited the answer to clarify. The second regex takes that into account, though.

Comment: Neither of those 2 statements work with PHP? See [link](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6te)

Comment: @Johannes: The second one will work, but you have to look at group 1 of the match, not the entire matched string.

Comment: how would I have to change the first regex, if I want optional exclusions? For example if I don't want to have  `color="` or `color=\"` to be preceding as well?

Comment: @Johannes: You can add them it as an alternation on the left side: `color=\\?"#[a-z]{6}|color:\s*#[a-z]{6}|(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})`. (Note that you'll have to use ``\\\\`` to match a literal backslash in PHP regex.)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your RegEx syntax I'm assuming you're using JavaScript, in which case negative lookbehind groups are not available. If you're looking to quickly get an array of matches I suggest this method:

```
var str = 'text etxta #aaaaaa#bys1a asdasd' +
    'a#bbbbbbbys1a asdasd' +
    'test style="color: #cccccc"';

var result = str.match(/(color:\s*)?#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}/g)
    .filter(function (match) {
        return !match.startsWith("color:");
    });
```